# Short story about a guy who plays a computer game that destroys actual alien ships

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to remember the name of a story I read some 20 years ago.

In the story a powerful alien civilisation is confronted by a strange enemy: a 2-dimensional rectangular shape that destroys their ships. The "shape" is actually a projection of a computer screen, and the "enemy" is a human that plays a computer game. The aliens figure out how to deal with the situation and capture the human, who is then judged for the many deaths he had inadvertently caused. While he is waiting for the judgement in a small capsule in space, his friend on Earth logs into the game, sees the capsule, and destroys it.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Only_You_Can_Save_Mankind

Comment: @Valorum I thought so too but it seems an odd fit.  IIRC, they don't judge Johnny, they surrender to him and expect him to fix the situation.  Still, you could post it as an answer.

Comment: Could it be Ender's Game?

Comment: Definitely not "Ender's Game" (read it recently) and not "Only You Can Save Mankind".

Comment: @Oleg I too initially thought "Ender's Game" except that very last piece.

Comment: @Valorum: I think so too. Could it be that the OP dont remember it correctly?
I dont know any other novel about a game that destroys "real" aliens. And the time slot would fit (1992 - 2019)

Comment: @Spkit2000 - OP [says it's not](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/207573/short-story-about-a-guy-who-plays-a-computer-game-that-destroys-actual-alien-shi?noredirect=1#comment567248_207573).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called "Game Over" ("Конец Игры" in Russian) by Oleg Kulagin. It was published in the science fiction section of [Tekhnika Molodezhi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tekhnika_Molodezhi) in June 1995.

I finally remembered that I had read it in my grandfather's magazine, but was not sure which one. Tekhnika Molodezhi was the best bet, but I had to go through a number of issues I found online before I could find the one I was looking for.

Comment: By the way, the computer in the story is [Iskra-1030](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iskra-1030). That means that 4.77 MHz and 640 KB RAM are enough to open a portal to a galaxy far far away.